# Unable to run Get-CASMailbox in Powershell using -filter clause with a pipeline variable

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I'm having some trouble with the syntax of Exchange cmdlet Get-CASMailbox.

I'm running in a 2007 environment and I've tested in PowerGUI 2.4, 3.0, and the PS ISE 2.0.

Sample code for demonstration purposes:

```
[String[]] $MailServerList = @('IP-0A207B07')

$MailServerList | %{            
Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize:10 -Filter {ServerName -eq $_}   
}
```

In this example there is only a single mailserver. During the call to Get-CASMailbox the pipeline operator $_ is IP-0A207B07 and $_.GetType() confirms it is a string. If this line runs I get the following error:

---

Get-CASMailbox : Cannot bind parameter 'Filter' to the target. Exception setting "Filter": "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automa
tion.PSObject' to type 'System.String'."
At C:\Users\erawlins\Desktop\MailboxFilterBug.ps1:7 char:38
+ Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize:10 -Filter <<<<  {ServerName -eq $_}
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-CASMailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetCASMailbox

---

I'm really confused by this. I've tried every syntax I could find and in every case attempting to use $_ throws the same error. If I just any other variable, such as $test=$_, and substitute that in the query it works fine.

Thinking there could be some problems with using the pipeline operator (maybe once Get-CASMailbox starts running something else is in $_) I also tried using an object property (which is part of the original code). The following two lines were added before the get-casmailbox call

```
$ServerInfo = "" | Select-Object Name
$ServerInfo.Name = $_.ToString()
```

Get-CASMailbox -ResultSize:10 -Filter {ServerName -eq $ServerInfo.Name}

Fails as well, same error message. So I'm really confused why taking $_ or $ServerInfo.Name and assigning it to $test, then using $test works fine but the first two methods throw an error. It seems to me that each of these should work as they're all strings. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$MailServerList | Foreach-Object { Get-CASMailbox -Filter "ServerName -eq  '$_'" }
```

Comment: Shay,

I tried your syntax and that did work. I previously tried the following which did not

$MailServerList | %{Get-CASMailbox -Filter {ServerName -eq "$_"}}

Looking at Jason's answer above and your example is the problem that the pipeline variable was included in a scriptblock? Does this mean that any code in a scriptblock is evaluated at some later time and $_ was out of scope then? By removing the script block it evaluated it immediately?

Comment: I believe that is what's going on and that's why I used a string filter so the value is expanded immediately before it passes on.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a scriptblock to the filter parameter and you are referencing an automatic variable ($*).  By the time the scriptblock gets evaluated, it could be inside some other code that is defining $*.  Always be careful while using automatic variables with nested scopes.